# Is it possible to get a users PFCG Role in UI5

Tags: sapui5, roles, sap-fiori

I have 2 applications that differ only in 1 button and it's function. 
This button should only be visible for a certain group.

If I stay with 2 apps, 2 tiles, only the members of said group would get the PFCG Role for the tile.

Is there a way to access the PFCG Roles of the fiori user inside the ui5 app? Or do something along the same lines?

Having 2 tiles that basically do the same seem redundant...

Thanks in advance,
Eric

Comment: Build a Function Import in your OData service that returns a Boolean flag which indicates whether the user has the role or not

Comment: thanks for the input, i ll try that